# Vim 'go to file' functionality

Tags: c#, vim, autocomplete

I'm looking for a good solution to the problem of trying to open any file in my source tree using tab completion/wildcard matching/Camel case etc. The difficulty I'm having is finding a method of doing this which works on a code base of ~30,000 files and ~7000 directories (including hidden .svn directories). Other programs (such as Resharper, or Sublime Text Editor) are able to jump to any file nearly instantly on this code base.

So far I have tried things like adding the recursive double star '**' to my Vim path and the FuzzyFinder plugin but neither are able to handle the large number of files and directories. Vim will either become entirely unresponsive or at least very sluggish with these methods.

Comment: Did you try all the available alternatives (CommandT, LustyExplorer…)? I think you will find this performance issue with all of those file navigation plugins. How does `<C-]>` and `:tag tagname` perform on such a huge codebase?

Comment: My guess (read I can almost guarantee it) is that the other solutions at the very least build a file with the directory structure, but that file is also likely loaded into memory. I'm not sure how you'd do that in Vim, or if there are any plugins that would take care of it for you, but that's what you'd want to look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once upon a time at an old project with a huge directory tree and thousands of files ago I did it like this (in an empty buffer):

```
:read !tree -af /PATH/TO/PROJECT
```

Et voila now I have a buffer with a directory tree. Now I can search that buffer with "standard" Vim regexes. If I had found the file, I just hit <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to jump to it.

If you don't have `tree` installed you can still go with:

```
:read !find /PATH/TO/PROJECT -type f -print 2>/dev/null
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I think I'm going to end up writing some functions or a plugin based on this to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Command-T](https://wincent.com/products/command-t). It supports camel case and is very smart about guessing which file you are trying to find.
I find it to be very stable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't try it, I've heard that [GNU GLOBAL](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) is extremely fast. You can use it by with [gtags.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=893).

Also help is [provided](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/globaldoc.html#SEC26) for how to use it in vim.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cool, never heard of this. I forgot to mention that I'm working with C#, which unfortunately GNU GLOBAL doesn't currently support.